# Getxattr and setxattr syscalls in c, MD5

Tags: c, md5

I am calculating MD5 for a file and then trying to write it in file's extended attribute. Before I call setxattr syscall I am printing it's value with this code in console and it works fine:

```
void print_value(unsigned char * md){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i <MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%02x",md[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Then I want to write it in extended attribute. Here is code for what I am doing:

```
unsigned char md[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH]; //I have stored MD5's value here.
//... some code to calculate md5's value
print_value(md); //it prints 7224c3e087d36ab8e99f21e670ea361a
setxattr(full_path, "user.hash", md, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH, 0);
int length = 0;
unsigned char buf[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
getxattr(full_path, "user.hash", buf, length); 
print_value(buf) //it prints 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

but when I try to print it's value after getxattr, it prints all zeroes. As I have searched, I am passing parameters correctly. I have no other idea why it prints different results, I am not doing anything else between setxattr and getxattr.

Comment: you didn't check the return value of setxattr.  did it return 0 or -1?  if it returned -1, what did it set errno to?

Comment: You're telling `getxattr` that your buffer has length `0`.

Comment: it returns 0. Using strace it calls setxattr("path-here", "user.hash", "r$\xc3\xe0\x87\xd3j\xb8\xe9\x9f!\xe6p\xea6\x1a", 16, 0) = 0 and getxattr("path-here", "user.hash", 0x7ffd03135010, 0) = 16.

Comment: @melpomene That's right. I thought it was used to write attributes length. I was not even passing it by reference. I have changed it and now it works. Thank you very, very much!